# Associate files with dates to query a specific date range, Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, date, google-cloud-firestore, days

I'm saving my data inside files (Google Firebase.Firestore) that are given the date as an ID when created. Files are put inside collection "Events". The structure looks like this:

```
Document 14-Jan-2019
ID: 1547504172
pr: "true"
po: "false"

Document 17-Jan-2019
ID: 1547763372
pr: "false"

...

Document 20-Jan-2019
ID: 1548025154
pr: "true"

Document 21-Jan-2019
ID: 1548107873
pr: "true"
```

IDs are created like this:

```
long ID = (long) Date().getTime()/1000
```

There is another collection called "Habits" that contains HabitInfo objects.

```
Document pr (object HabitInfo)
name: "pr"
startDay: 1547504172 //14-Jan-2019
points: 12 ...
```

Each object has a startDay parameter that specifies the beginning of the week being observed.

I would like to get all files whose dates of creation (in form of long numbers) are *less than seven days* after my startDay. **The time of the day doesn't matter, only the date.**

I tried doing something like this:

```
CollectionReference colRef = db.collection("events");
Query query = colRef.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("ID", hInfo.startDay)
                    .whereLessThan("ID", hInfo.startDay + 7*24*60*60);
```

The problem with this is that time difference between two of my IDs can be more than 7 days (converted to seconds) because they are recorded at different times of the day. For example, Monday 14th at 7 A.M. and Monday 21st at 3 P.M. are more than seven days away when looking at values in seconds.

How can I get a range considering only dates?

Comment: Don't describe code, but share the minimal complete standalone code that reproduces the problem please. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: You need to decide on a time zone for the operation. At the point in time that your `long startDay` specifies it is not the same date everywhere on this planet.

Comment: It’s a job for java.time, the modern Java date and time API. [Tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If you are not yet on API level 26 you get java,time through the backport, ThreeTenABP, see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Your ID is in seconds since the epoch. You need the files from the start of the day indicated by `startDay` and the following week (end day exclusive). Convert the time to a date using `Instant.ofEpochSecond(startDay).atZone(yourDesiredZoneId).toLocalDate()`. To add 7 days use `.plusDays(7)`. To convert back to seconds since the epoch for comparison with the files, use `yourDate.atStartOfDay(yourDesiredZoneId).toInstant().getEpochSecond()`.